# Entering multiple records on same HTML page

Tags: javascript, forms

I am creating a JS form where i need 3 inputs from user and after typing the 3 inputs , on clicking 'Add record' button ,it should display them on the same page one after another (line by line) for every button click. With my code, it is writing every new input entry in the same line and not next line. How do i do it ?

My result:
Andrew Arts 2007 Evelyn Computers 2006

Expected result :

## Andrew Arts 2007

Evelyn Computers 2006

```js
function doSubmit() {


  document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML += document.myform.name.value + " ";
  document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML += document.myform.major.value + " ";
  document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML += document.myform.year.value + " ";



  return false;

}
```

```html
<body>

  <form name="myform">
    <p>
      Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="name" size="30" type="text" /> course: <input name="major" size="30" type="text" /> Year : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="year" size="4" type="text" />
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="Add record" onClick='doSubmit(); return false' />

  </form>
  <p id='f1'></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please ignore the bold "Andrew arts 2007" . It is required as a normal text.

Comment: just add a ``<br>`` tag before doing a ``return`` to the inner html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a `<br>` tag to break the line inside a `<p>` tag.

You just have to make a small change in your `function` :

```
function doSubmit() {

    document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML += document.myform.name.value + " ";
    document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML += document.myform.major.value + " ";
    document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML += document.myform.year.value + " ";
    document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML +='<br />'

    return false;
  }
```

If you're looking to style your form values , it would be good to append `<p>`tag for each form value . It will require a small change like below :

```
function doSubmit() {

    document.getElementById('form-value').innerHTML += '<p>'+ document.myform.name.value + " " + document.myform.major.value + " " + document.myform.year.value + " " + "</p>";

    return false;

}
```

**Your HTML :**

```
<body>

<form name="myform">
    <p>
        Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="name" size="30" type="text" /> course: <input name="major" size="30"
            type="text" /> Year : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="year" size="4" type="text" />
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="Add record" onClick='doSubmit(); return false' />

</form>
<div id="form-value">

</div>
```

Comment: That was great ! solved the problem in minutes ! Thanks :)

Comment: @pun_intended happy coding :)

Comment: @pun_intended consider swapping `innerHTML` with `innerText`. Using `innerHTML` for storing the user input can leat to XSS attacks. You can check my answer for an example with `innerText` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new `p` element for every submitted input. You also don't want to store the user input into the `innerHTML`, because it can lead to cross-site scripting attacks. To prevent this, you can use `innerText` instead. Here is an example of how you can achieve all that with your code:

```
function doSubmit() {
    const newInputParagraph = document.createElement("p");

    newInputParagraph.innerText += document.myform.name.value + " ";
    newInputParagraph.innerText += document.myform.major.value + " ";
    newInputParagraph.innerText += document.myform.year.value + " ";

    document.getElementById("inputs").appendChild(newInputParagraph);
}
```

And you need to add container for input results (simple `div`) to your markup, for example like this:

```
<form name="myform">
    <p>
        Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="name" size="30" type="text" /> course: <input name="major" size="30" type="text" /> Year : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="year" size="4" type="text" />
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="Add record" onClick='doSubmit(); return false' />
</form>

<div id="inputs"></div>
```